# Re Order a list of div by change node parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use .sortable but i don't know why, it doesn't work.

My purpose is : re order a list of div and change parent node like the menu in wordpress admin. If it's possible, when I move the div, show the placeholder.

In my example above, I can't just sort the div... only 'drop' into another and sometimes, I've this error on FF :

```
HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy
```

My code (very basic) :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

     $(".node").sortable({
        connectWith: ".node"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

I've create a fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/wwzu6qbr/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wwzu6qbr/5/

You have used class `node` for the parent and the children divs and you used class `node` for the sortable, it's trying to make all divs on the document sortable. You need to use a different class for child divs.

```
<div class="node">
    <div class="nodea">Contain 1</div>
    <div class="nodea depth_1">Under Contain 1</div>
    <div class="nodea">Contain 2</div>
    <div class="nodea">Contain 3</div>
    <div class="nodea">Contain 4</div>
    <div class="nodea">Contain 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! it's working but if I want to change node parent : example, move "Under Contain 1" to the root, by remove depth_1 style css, how can I do it?

Comment: @Portekoi I think you mean drop `Under Contain 1` under `.node` and remove its class upon drop. There's probably a `dropped` or `sorted` callback, on which you can remove the class. I don't know what the answer is but it sounds like a new question.